# Giteye cannot import repository

Tags: eclipse, git, giteye

I am working with the latest version of GitEye and I cannot import local repositories.

When I try that it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException. Does anyone have a solution for that?

As far as I know GitEye uses JGit and is based on eclipse.

Here are the error details:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @user.home/.giteye

org.eclipse.egit.ui
Error
Tue Jul 04 22:42:45 CEST 2017
Error occurred

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog$11.isDotGit(RepositorySearchDialog.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog$11.isGitInternal(RepositorySearchDialog.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog$11.preVisitDirectory(RepositorySearchDialog.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog$11.preVisitDirectory(RepositorySearchDialog.java:1)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog.findGitDirsRecursive(RepositorySearchDialog.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog.access$12(RepositorySearchDialog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositorySearchDialog$12.run(RepositorySearchDialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is not similar to [bug 513744](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513744) and [bug 509827](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509827)

> NPE if adding existing repository

This was fixed in EGit 4.7 in March 2017, which might not be used by GitEye.

Comment: Reads familiar, do you have an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: @Knerd Check with collabnet (https://www.collab.net/products/giteye) if they will include Egit 4.7 soon in their product dependencies.